# Can I get a UK tourist visa after being deported from Greece?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, greece, deportation

I volunteered for deportation and was deported in September 2018 from the Schengen zone (Greece) for illegal entrance and stay. My girlfriend came with me (she is from the UK); we will be married in the next months. Will it be possible for me to get a regular tourist visa to visit her family and friends in the UK?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85617/discussion-on-question-by-sasha-rose-can-i-get-a-uk-tourist-visa-after-being-dep).